# How to display image from link in DataGridView without downloading it

Tags: c#, mysql, image, winforms, datagridview

I have a program that displays a list of downloadable apps with an icon column in it. It gets the data from a MySQL database, but it gets the image as a link.

Is there a way to display that image without downloading it to the client computer? If there is, can someone tell me how? If there isn't can someone tell me how to have the code check if the image for that row is downloaded, and if it is then display it, and if it isn't, then download it from a URL and display it?

Please provide some details or links to sites with details, because this is my first time doing anything like this, and I only started wit C# about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: "How to get the bits without getting them". "How to eat dinner without ingesting anything". You can't. You can't display an image on the screen without getting the image. Just like you can't display text on the screen without getting the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that your question looks broad to me and you can find the answer via using your favorite search engine web site. Here are the answers along with small sample application at the end.

1. No, you can not get the image without downloading it. The URL is just a plain text which points to the image somewhere in the Internet Universe.
2. Yet no. If someone finds it he should receive a Noble Prize.
3. If you know what is the path where the image is stored locally, you just have to check if this file still exists.
4. If it does not exists locally, then obviously you need to download it.
5. Once you download it, you just have to present it to the DataGridView under an appropriate column which recognizes images.

Here is the promised small sample application to get you started.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
        }

        private DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(Image));

            // Path to store locally the image
            string imageLocalPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "image.ico";

            if (File.Exists(imageLocalPath))
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { Image.FromFile(imageLocalPath) });                    
            }
            else
            {
                // Get request to download the image if it does not exist locally
                var request = WebRequest.Create("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d");

                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Check if the request is successful
                    if ((response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                        image.Save(imageLocalPath);

                        dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { image });
                    }
                    // No local image exist and the URL is no longer valid
                    else
                    {
                        // The default Windows Forms image will be displayed
                    }
                }
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way I could download and use the image without actually storing the file? because the list of apps will be edited from a site instead of the app, so an app is removed then the image will still be there, unused... also, I need the image to "detect" what row it is in. For example, if I have an installer for visual studio, it needs to have the image for visual studio. How do I do that?